# resizeing image spring mvc

Tags: image, resize, bufferedimage

I'm trying to upload and resize an inputstream to bufferedimage and save the image into a folder. 
I can upload the image to the folder but when the size of the image is zero.
I use The Buzz Media and spring mvc.

Pleas any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public BufferedImage convertInputStremToBufferedImage(InputStream uploadedInputStream)
{

    try
    {
        BufferedImage buff=ImageIO.read(uploadedInputStream);
        buff=Scalr.resize(buff,  Scalr.Method.SPEED, Scalr.Mode.FIT_TO_WIDTH,
                150, 150, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
        String path="/Mac/myfiles/uploaded/";
        BufferedImage outPad= Scalr.pad(buff, 200);

        ImageIO.write(buff, "jpg", new File(path + ".jpg"));
        return outPad;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please check this URL https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/